# pm2 Ecosystem Global Variables

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have `pm2.ecosystem.json` file like below

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "script": "build/index.js",
      "cwd": "../services/api/",
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "instances": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "api-2",
      "script": "build/index.js",
      "cwd": "../services/api-2/",
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "instances": 1
    }
  ],
  "env": {
      "TEST": "TEST",
      "OTHER": "OTHER"
   }
}
```

When I run my project, I can not reach that `env` variables. How can I describe my `env` variables to all `pm2` apps. It has to be common for all `pm2` apps.